# Read error with epoll on a (pre)forked server

Tags: c, linux, fork, epoll

I am starting to learn about epoll and wanted to create a small server to play with it. There are lots of discussions about it on the web but I can't manage to put my hands on a reliable documentation...

Here is the structure of the program I have so far (i've cleaned it up for clarity) :

```
int sfd = create_and_bind(PORT_NUMBER);
make_non_blocking(sfd);
listen(sfd);

int efd = epoll_create1(0);
event.data.fd = sfd;
event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sfd, &event);

struct epoll_event *events = calloc(MAXEVENTS, sizeof event);

int p, pid = 1;
for (p = 0; p < 2; ++i) {
    if (pid > 0) {
        pid = fork();
    }
}

if(pid == 0) {
    while(1) {
        int n, i;
        n = epoll_wait(efd, events, MAXEVENTS, -1);
        for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if ((events[i].events & EPOLLERR) || (events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) || (!(events[i].events & EPOLLIN))) {
                // Closing socket
                close(events[i].data.fd);
                continue;
            } else if (sfd == events[i].data.fd) {
                // incoming connection

                int infd = accept(sfd, &in_addr, &in_len);
                // Break while if call blocks
                make_socket_non_blocking(infd);

                event.data.fd = infd;
                event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
                epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, infd, &event);
            } else {
                // Ready to read
                ssize_t count = read(events[i].data.fd, buf, sizeof buf);

                //
                // Here I get some problems
                //
                if (count == -1) {
                    /* If errno == EAGAIN, that means we have read all
                     data. So go back to the main loop. */
                    if (errno != EAGAIN) {
                        perror("read");
                        done = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                } else if (count == 0) {
                    /* End of file. The remote has closed the
                     connection. */
                    done = 1;
                    break;
                }

                if(done) {
                    close(events[i].data.fd);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've done a simple forked client to test this with 10 concurrent connection and I get almost every time one :

```
read : Bad file descriptor
```

Am I missing something here ?

Thanks

PS : I have only left the bits of code I thought was relevant... Here is the rest : http://pastebin.com/5VTTuNFT

Comment: You might want to create the epoll fd after the fork, not before it.

Comment: OK please answer below so I can validate your answer :)